# GCM project cannot connect to FCM host

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, chrome-gcm, android-push-notification

I am trying to ensure that my GCM client application can receive downstream messages from my new FCM project to ensure backward compatibility. I know google says it should work and several people have commented that it is successful but I have to independently verify this.

I changed the "senderID" on my client app to the new FCM project specified in "settings">"cloud messaging">"senderId"

Is there something else I need to do? Do I need to make any more changes to point this project? I am able to generate a "registrationId" so the client can connect to the project but no messages are received when I try to send messages downstream using the "notifications" system in the project. Am I missing something?

Comment: why not update to FCM instead?

Comment: We are trying to update. But some customers will not update their version of the app so we need to ensure GCM notification clients work correctly.